# How to render Chart.js (ver. 1.0.2) chart image with it's legend?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like to create a feature that allows me to download generated chart as an image.

So far, I am able to generate an image of actual chart by using: `myLineChart.toBase64Image();` but that image lacks legend.

Any clues on how I can add a legend to generated image?